# Grub doesn't see ssd install

Tags: boot, ssd, grubrescue

I have just installed ubuntu server 16.04 in an SSD, the installation went fine, up until the restart point, where I get:

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

when I ls I can only see the hard drives (that I am planning to configure later) but not the ssd where I installed ubuntu... if I run Gparted, I see all of the drives and the ssd has all the expected partitions.
How can I solve this?

Running the commands I get:

```
lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid
```

[image]

```
# parted -l
/bin/sh: 2: parted: not found
```

Edit 3: I used a desktop iso to access the system live. Here are the results for the commands:

```
$ sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid
NAME        MOUNTPOINT LABEL         SIZE FSTYPE   UUID
sdb                                  7.3T          
loop0       /rofs                    1.4G squashfs 
sdc                                  7.5G          
└─sdc1      /cdrom     MYLINUXLIVE   7.5G vfat     90F0-887B
sda                                  7.3T          
nvme0n1                              477G          
├─nvme0n1p3                        448.4G swap     0332355b-9189-49bf-9053-b53f15a3efef
├─nvme0n1p1                            1M          
└─nvme0n1p2                         28.6G ext4     a10d9ce6-c110-40ba-844a-9baaaf8a9a0d
```

[image]

Comment: Will you run `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l` and append the text output to your question?

Comment: You added a picture of some of the text to your question.  You didn't add the actual text.  Which version of Ubuntu are you running?  `parted` is installed by default on Ubuntu.  It would help to understand what is happening if you copied and pasted the command from the comment to your terminal, then ran the exact command.  Then copy the text output from your terminal (including the actual command) and paste the full content to your question.  There's a significant difference between the actual text and a picture of the text.

Comment: Disregard my last message.  I'm noticing that you don't have a graphic option.  I'm going to study another way of identifying what is going wrong.

Comment: well, the picture contains all the output lsblk gave, I mentioned Ubuntu version at the begining of the question. and I can't copy paste since I can't start the system... :/ so I could copy the exact text but that is just losing some time.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It doesn't totally waste time.  While I apologize for initially missing the `grubrescue` mode you're in, my addressing the difference between text and pictures of text for the content, brought this to my attention to realize exactly where we are working.  I understand the details are obvious to you, and most, but on rare occasions, I might miss an obvious detail as in this case.  I'm currently spending time to try to make sure I have all the details included before providing another diagnostic step.

Comment: ok, I understand your point thank you, I appreciate the time you are taking into this :)

Comment: I highly suggest you use boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair IF boot repair fails post the link to the pastebin.

Comment: The commandline I gave you above was to be run from your Live Boot Disk, not from the boot rescue prompt.  If you run it from the Live Boot Disk, you'll be able to log in to AS from there and post the output.  Seeing the output I would be able to give you pretty exact steps to rectify the boot problem.  The output will provide info for other questions such as UEFI mode.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I'm using Ubuntu **server**, which does not include a 'live' version in the iso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now re-installed Ubuntu server making some changes in BIOS before installation, the relevant one being:

Change boot to UEFI **before** installing.

After that the booting was normal.