# How to boot into GRUB Rescue Mode (Forcing Rescue Mode)

Tags: 16.04, grub2, grubrescue

Can someone tell me of the steps to boot into the **Grub Rescue** mode?  I spent some time researching this.  The results I'm finding is either discussing what to do when you're that mode and how to get out of it.

Other pages are discussing how to get into **Recovery Mode** (which I find easy, but it's a different mode.

The rescue mode (I believe) has this prompt `grub rescue>`.

I'm trying to get into the mode so that I can test out the various commands available for accessing and recovering the system.  The purpose is to be able to provide support to someone who is stuck in the mode.  I'm trying to test methods of diagnosing the system from this mode.

Answer (score 2):

The `grub rescue>` prompt only appears if grub can not find it's config files. In this event only the insmod (see insmod), ls (see ls), set (see set), and unset (see unset) commands are normally available.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Commands.html for details

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell.html#GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting for details.

You hit "c" to get grub prompt. From the grub prompt you can run all the grub commands and it should be adequate for testing.

FWIW the best advice to give if someone is having problems with grub / booting to grub prompt or grub rescue is to have them run boot-repair

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Boot repair has multiple advantages. It is a graphical interface and it it fails produces meaningful output for debugging in a pastebin.

> Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished,
>   note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then
>   reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  This is what I have already been finding before.  I'm very familiar with how to recover from the Grub Rescue mode.  I'm trying to get into it so that I can explore it more.  On every occasion that I have had it in my environment, once getting out of it, I have always wanted to revisit it so that I can see the other options.  I appreciate that you are listing the many options, as well as all the pages I find about the options.  But I'm trying to actually view and explore **first hand** the many options.

Comment: I'll try the `c` at the Grub prompt and advise you of how it works... thanks again!

Comment: As I said, hit "c" for a grub prompt. The only thing special about rescue mode is the lack of config files. If you must move or delete the grub config file but then you will have to run boot-repair or boot to a live cd to recover your system. Doing so just to display the `grub rescue>` prompt is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Hitting the `c` brings up what appears to be the Grub Command prompt.  I believe this is a different mode from the **Grub Rescue** mode.  I'm trying to test options for assisting with [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/921468/29012).  From the content of the question it appears that he's seeing this **`grub rescue`** as his prompt.  Hitting the 'c' gives this prompt: `grub>`.  I suggested for the user to provide the output of `lsblk`, which works.  `lsblk` doesn't work at the `grub>` prompt.  I don't think the modes are the same.

Comment: See https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-grub-and-grub-rescue-prompt-in-linux . I suppose it depends on what is wrong with the system. grub rescue allows you to chroot.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to help me to explore the available commands and features of the mode.  I'm very fluent with the command prompt and most of the commands that I'm seeing in my research.  I gave the user two command `lsblk` and `parted -l`.  One was available and worked.  The other wasn't.  If I could actually invoke the mode (if it's possible) I could test the exact commands and not have to guess which ones will work and which ones won't... (cont)

Comment: Well keep in mind, what will and will not work strongly depends also on what is wrong with the system.

Comment: ...also the `chroot` would be a great option for diagnosing the problem in the other answer (why he's not seeing his `ssd` drive.  I understand there are many alternatives for fixing the problem.  But since he's in the mode and has the prompt, I would just like to actually test the commands that I'm giving.  For me it would be to identify the current booted device and configuration, and verify the desired boot device and configuration... all from the `grub rescue` mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59755/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-bodhi-zazen).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest, install `xorriso`:

```
sudo apt install xorriso
```

create a GRUB rescue image:

```
grub-mkrescue -o grub.iso
```

boot your system using grub.iso